# Can you still embed swf files to websites in 2017?

Tags: html, flash, web, embed

Thew update of flash isn't supported my Google chrome anymore. I need to embed a flash game onto my website because it is our capstone project. Is there any way for swf files to still be usable on the web?

Comment: use canvas not flash .

Comment: @LalitBhakuni I like your enthusiasm but without a V.M (virtual machine) to handle the swf bytecode I ask.. what part of canvas can render a compiled swf application so we all don't have to use the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

yes, with a (probably older) browser that supports it still (http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2465543/mozilla-firefox-is-latest-browser-to-kill-off-adobe-flash-support).

just for demonstration purpose you could show that with e.g. an older portable version (for flash … https://portableapps.com/support/firefox_portable#plugins).

but I would recommend to get rid of the idea to use flash in browsers as soon as possible.
flash is a huge security problem for years and people want to use the web mobile and flash is not so much mobile or anything without support in browsers.